# Cache evict a single object in java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching

I am trying to cache a list of object, let say 'Orders'. It caches it perfectly.

to put a new object in a cache list what I am doing is this;

```
    cacheManager.getCacheNames().parallelStream().forEach(name -> cacheManager.getCache(name).put("order", order));
```

And to evict that specific order from the cache I did;

```
    cacheManager.getCacheNames().parallelStream().forEach(name -> cacheManager.getCache(name).evict(orderId));
```

But evict doesn't work for me.

How can I remove/ update the out dated object in a cache? Is there a way to iterate a cache until I get the desired object and update it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For putting object to the cache you should use `orderId` instead of string value `"order"`

```
cacheManager.getCacheNames().parallelStream().forEach(name -> cacheManager.getCache(name).put(orderId, order));
```

Comment: cache PUT works fine. but it doesn't evict the old entry.
Let say if my cache has 10 order entries. then, after the put I have 11 entries. with the updated object and the old one.

How do I evict the old one?

Comment: @Muneeb what actual cache provider are you using?

Comment: @Muneeb for updating old entity by new one you need call `put` method with the same key.

Comment: I am using spring mvc, I have defined bean in dispatcher-servlet.
I have logged the cache, after I called Put method with the same key as 'orderId'.
But no luck. 

the cache appends the new object but doesn't remove the old one.

Comment: where do I have to define the key? or no where?
And also do I have to use any annotation on that function in controller

Comment: How did you define that old object was not removed?

Comment: I logged it.

        log.info(cacheManager.getCache("orders").getNativeCache());